# WSO2APIM error when adding Keycloak as key manager when both running in separate docker containers on localhost

Tags: docker, keycloak, wso2-api-manager

Keycloak is running in docker container via wsl (ubuntu) on localhost, and WSO2APIM is running in a separate container on localhost too and I am trying to import  http://localhost:8080/realms/MyRealm/.well-known/openid-configuration/  into Well Known URL for adding keycloak as keymanager for WSO2 APIM on this portal https://localhost:9443/admin/settings/key-managers/create

It gives the below error -

The server encountered an internal error. Please contact administrator. However I can access the link in my browser.

PS, 1) Have already exported the keystore.crt into wso2apim directory on docker container - /wso2am-4.0.0/repository/resources/security
2) Have setup wso2apim as a client in keycloak with required details
3) Have configured KEycloak as Service provider and identity provider on /carbon portal

Am I missing something?

New to docker, keycloak and wso2apim.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you see an error in the server logs (console logs)? It could be because APIM is looking for localhost within the container while keycloak exists outside

Answer (score 0):

The reason was both docker containers run in isolation. So I did the following to get wsl network ip address -

> wsl
> **ifconfig**
> get something like this as output -

docker0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet <**IP_ADDRESS_REQUIRED**>  netmask   broadcast

http://IP_ADDRESS_REQUIRED:8080/realms/MyRealm/.well-known/openid-configuration/

and it worked, atleast imported the urls that I would have otherwise had to do manually that too with a suspect of it being able to connect to keycloak or not.

Thanks!